# Is it possible to write a proposal to get a junior professor position in Germany, when existing openings seem far from my research interests?

Tags: career-path, job-search, faculty-application, germany

It has been several months that I am looking for a juniorprofessor position in German institutes. Basically there are just a few opening which are far from my research interests. I have a good publication record and I was involved in writing funding proposals. Is it possible to write a proposal to ask for a professorship position?

P.S. My research lies in computer science and electrical engineering.

Comment: Your profile says you are a PhD student in Germany. In this case, it might be helpful to talk to your advisor about your future career. To see if they would support you to pursue a career in the German system. If they are reluctant, then you may as well forget about getting a professorship in Germany.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Such positions are sometimes created and attached to full W3 professors, essentially as a temporary *Assistent* in the old parlance (compare C1). Whether this is actually done may depend on your field, your *Bundesland* (you are in Baden-Württemberg, where this is possible in general) and even your university.

You may want to talk to your supervisor, who may have the most vested interest in having you continue on board, especially if you have a proven track record and/or specialized knowledge. However, it would probably be better for your CV to get a "normal" *Juniorprofessur* to show that you can stand on your own feet, rather than continue in your supervisor's working group.

---

Alternatively, there are ways of getting funding for a few years that may not be a *Juniorprofessur* in name, but in effect. For instance, the DFG's [Emmy Noether Program](http://www.dfg.de/en/research_funding/programmes/individual/emmy_noether/index.html). After a few years funded through this program, you will be considered *berufbar*. You will need to apply with your own research proposal.

The advantage is that this is very competitive, and if you snag one of these, it is a true mark of excellence. In addition, you will be independent of senior professors, and it offers quite a number of networking opportunities. If you can manage to get one of these, it would be ideal.

Answer (score 16):

Stephan's answer is generally correct, but I get the feeling that this is not what the OP has in mind:

> Is it possible to write a proposal to ask for a professorship position?

I take this to mean whether it makes sense to essentially do a "blind application" for a professor position (i.e., send to a university that is not currently conducting a suitable search an application to the extend of "here are my credentials and a research proposal, please create me a position"). The answer to this question is a pretty resounding **no**. This will only make you seem out of touch with how academia works.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you should wait till the next application season, which generally starts around fall (October-November). Most universities start posting job adverts around that time. You can apply for faculty positions that are available even if the requirements do not strictly match your CV. Meanwhile, inform your colleagues, peers, professors (basically as many people as possible in your network) that you are looking for such a position. Hopefully, if they know of any such upcoming position, they'll pass on the information to you.